# Google Spreadsheet Query return string from cell for 'contains'

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a big table containing data about a volleyball tournament. Every game is listed with date, players and result.
I created a drop down list, containing all player names. By selecting the name the stats of each player are shown, like how many wins and losses.

Now I also want to list all games this player has played. To do this I found the `QUERY` function. I use it like this:

```
=QUERY(A4:G; "select * where (B contains '<name>') or (C contains '<name>') or (D contains '<name>') or (E contains '<name>')")
```

Now I want to replace `<name>` with the playername selected in the drop down list (which in my case would be cell AS24).

How can I do this?

This is my table:
[Table](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19hbj1btAnuyu4xNxachgE1yu0xMSyCO7XePXFqPEhDs/edit?usp=docslist_api)

Thanks in advance!

Dambe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
=QUERY(A4:G; "select * where B="""&AS24&""" or C="""&AS24&""" or D="""&AS24&""" or E="""&AS24&"""")
```

Is it **AS24** or **AS4**?

I just tried this and it works:

```
=QUERY(A4:G; "select * where B="""&AS4&""" or C="""&AS4&""" or D="""&AS4&""" or E="""&AS4&"""")
```

Comment: You forgot **&** on both sides. Just copy paste my second formula

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot. Can you give a short  explanation why it works with so many " and &?

Comment: I can try, it's the way Google Query works. 1 " will close the rule, but 2 makes it inside the rule, third one allows you to reference the cell from outside. I know it looks weird, but it is just a common rule when adding external cells to the Query. Also & is needed to combine, for example if you want to type text in cell with something from another cell you would type: "Hello"&A1&" How are you"